# query to get the count of all id from a particular coloumn of table

Tags: mysql

How to write a query to count all field data from a particular column of a table? I've been trying this for past 5 hours without a success.

Please help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand this question. "of all id from a particular column"? What does that mean? There is a column in your table and sometimes it holds an ID and sometimes something else? Please elaborate. Also show sample data, desired output, and the query you've tried.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: i want to count the column field data

Comment: Usually you'd count *records*. Either all `COUNT(*)` or only those where a column (or expression) is not null `COUNT(colname)`. Is that what you are looking for? This is very basic. Again, I'd recommend you learn these SQL basics, before doing things you don't actually understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want count of a specific value only

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'your_value'
```

If you want all distinct values in a column with their respective counts, use this

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name
```

Comment: @rose, do you want count of all records of one value or count of all distinct values with their count

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select ID,count(ID) as `count`
from tableName
group by ID;
```

Comment: throwing error: 1054 - Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Then what's the column name??

Comment: column name is field_strainid_1 but its still throwing error

Comment: @rose: Sorry to say this, but if *this* is giving you trouble already, then it's just too early for you to write such query. Get yourself a book on SQL (or an online tutorial for that matter) and learn. Then see, if you can't solve your problem yourself.